# Why z-index has no effect?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need text be above the image, so I set `z-index`to 10, and image to 5.

Text is in `Navbar`.

```js
function ProductList2(props: OrganizationList2) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.container1}>
        <Navbar />
        <img
          src="/Olovka_Studio_gyűrű_v2.png"
          width="100"
          height="140"
          className={styles.img1}
        />
```

```css
.container1 {
  background-color: #12341b;
  position: relative;
  height: 38vw; /*543/1440*/
}

.img1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 11vw; /*159/1440*/
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 38vw;
  width: 24vw; /*372/1440*/
}

.container { /* <------------------ Inside Navbar*/
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 8vw; /*128/1440*/
  margin-right: 8vw; /*430/1440*/
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-height: 88px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: why the parentheses are open tho?

Comment: I copied only relevant part of the component

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index: _"Applies to: positioned elements"_ - and, is `.container` positioned in _any_ way here ...?

Comment: add ``position: absolute;`` or ``position: relative;``  to ``.container ``

Comment: What is `.container1` actually doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element with `z-index` doesn't work without a `position` element

Try:

```
.div-with-z-index {
   position: relative /* Relative doesn't change the position of the element itself. */
}
```